# Validar identificador de cliente para exportar en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql, sql-server-2012

Amigos buenas noches, espero poder explicarme bien sobre el problema que estoy teniendo. Actualmente estoy haciendo una exportación en SQL Con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT        IDFactura, FechaDocumento, NombreCliente, NIT, DireccionFacturacion, FOLIO, Subfolio, Habitacion, SERIE, NumeroDoc, IDVendor, IDClienteIQware, DocType
FROM            POS_EDIFAC.dbo.V_InvoiceHeader
WHERE FechaDocumento = (SELECT CurrentHotelDate -1 FROM prProperty)
```

Obteniendo un resultado así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparte tengo una tabla de clientes con esta estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es utilizar el valor `NIT` Que es un código único de identificación del cliente para hacer una comparación entre esta consulta y la tabla de clientes y de esta forma sustituir el valor de la columna `IDClienteIQware` con la información guardada en la tabla de `ClientesCXC` en la columna `IDSAP`, les dejo un resultado aproximado de lo que necesito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen, durante mi primera consulta necesito comparar el `NIT` con el `NIT` de la tabla de `ClientesCXC` y sustituir con el valor con el de la columna `IDSAP` e insertarlos en la columna `IDClienteIQware`.

Espero haberme explicado bien, es un tema algo complicado pero sé que lo entenderán, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿y no se puede que hagas una consulta relacionada (join)? o no entendí bien cuál es el problema

Comment: Fijate que cuando hago Join solo me devuelve los datos que encuentra en la tabla de ClientesCxC. pero al haber más clientes que no aplican y que no se encuentran allí, me elimina todos los demás. Yo quisiera que los que sí se encuentran sustituirlos por el valor de IDSAP y los que no se encuentran ponerles un valor genérico, como "CF"

Comment: El primer problema que comentas es producto de la naturaleza de un `inner join`, para lo que buscas pareciera ser mejor el `left join`, que te traerá siempre todas las filas de una tabla y solo aquellas que coincidan de la tabla relacionada.